# How to get an array for use with nested attributes in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

The docs describe passing nested arrays, but never actually give an example of how the form fields themselves would look like

```
  params = { :member => {
    :name => 'joe', :posts_attributes => [
      { :title => 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!' },
      { :title => 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen' },
      { :title => '', :_destroy => '1' } # this will be ignored
    ]
  }}
```

This is the only way I can think of for this to actually work. Is this correct, and am I left to my own devices to come up with a way to number the array elements (using an incrementer) or is there a RoR-specific way to do this?

```
name='member[posts_attributes][0][title]' value='Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!'
name='member[posts_attributes][1][title]' value='The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen'
```

Something like this?

```
- f.fields_for "posts_attributes[#{i}]", x do |pa|
```

Or am I way off?

Answer (score 0):

Rails is supposed to take care of everything if your models are properly nested.

Based on your example, make sure that:

```
Member has_many :post_attributes
Member accepts_nested_fields_for :post_attributes
```

And then, on your create action, you have to build the number of post_attribute objects that you want to show:

```
def create
  @member = Member.new
  @member.post_attributes.build
end
```

Your form should only need:

```
f.fields_for :post_attributes do |post_attributes_form|
  post_attributes_form.text_field :title
```

Answer (score 0):

Railscasts [196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) do a good job of explaining what your after.

Also note in Rails 3.1 your `f.fields_for` should start with a `=` not a `-`

```
= f.fields_for(:posts) do |posts_form|
```